# Wie schreibt man zusammengesetzte Adjektive aus Nomen und Verben?

Tags: capitalization, compound

Wird ein Adjektiv, das sich aus einem Nomen und einem Verb zusammensetzt, groß- oder kleingeschrieben? Wie ist das mit dem Bindestrich?

Mein konkretes Beispiel:

> ein Fluoreszenz-markiertes Protein
>
> ein fluoreszenz-markiertes Protein
>
> ein fluoreszenzmarkiertes Protein

Comment: Ohne eine genaue Regel zu kennen: Das dritte Beispiel *fluoreszenzmarkiert* ist auf jeden Fall korrekt. Bindestriche werden bei Komposita nur der besseren Lesbarkeit halber eingefügt. Ebenso, wie *Fregattenkapitänspatent* korrekt ist, ist also auch *fluoreszenzmarkiert* korrekt. Für diese Schreibweise ist es irrelevant, ob die Zusammensetzung aus Nomen und Verb oder zwei Adjektiven erfolgt. Was rauskommt ist ein Adjektiv und das wird immer klein geschrieben. Daraus würde sich ergeben, dass auch die Variante mit Bindestrich kleingeschrieben werden müsste - Adjektiv bleibt Adjektiv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjektive werden **prinzipiell kleingeschrieben**, egal wie sie gebildet werden. Das gilt auch für geographische Bezeichnungen ...

> Die pazifischen Küstenregionen, die österreichischen Bundesländer

... und auch für von Eigennamen abgeleitete Adjektive:

> der gregorianische Kalender, die napoleonischen Kriege, kafkaesk, darwinistisch ...

Aber natürlich gibt es Ausnahmen: Adjektive werden großgeschrieben, wenn sie von **Orts- oder Ländernamen auf -er** abgeleitet sind ...

> die Römer Verträge (aber: die römischen Märkte), die Innsbrucker Innenstadt, die Pariser Metro

... es sich um **feststehende Namen** handelt ...

> das Rote Kreuz, der Deutsche Fußballbund

... oder, bei von **Personennamen** abgeleiteten Adjektiven **auf -sch**, ein **Apostroph** zur Verdeutlichung des Personennamens steht:

> ein Freud'scher Versprecher, Shakespeare'sche Dramen, Potemkin'sche Dörfer

Ansonsten bleibt es bei der Kleinschreibung:

> ein carbon-verstärkter Werkstoff, eine wasserstoff-emittierende Reaktion

Bindestriche sind optional und werden nur der leichteren Lesbarkeit wegen gesetzt.

Comment: Die Antwort mit dem Vitamin B sowie diese Frage https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/gro%C3%9F-und-kleinschreibung-und-bindestrich-bei-substantiv-adjektiv-zusammensetzun beantworten diese Frage m. E. besser/richtiger, insb. mit dem Hinweis auf Regeln und Quellen. Die richtige Antwort wäre also *Floureszenz-markiert* oder *Carbon-verstärkt* (bei *Wasserstoff emittierend* einfach den Bindestrich weglassen, dann stellt sich die Frage nicht mehr).

Comment: Das glaube ich nicht. Ich halte "Vitamin-B-haltig" für eine absolute Ausnahme, die wohl dem "B" geschuldet ist; ansonsten spräche nämlich nichts gegen _vitaminhaltig_.

Comment: Warum es *Vitamin-B-haltig*, aber *vitaminhaltig*, heißt steht in der akzeptierten Antwort der von mir verlinkten Frage (kurz: Nomen in Zusammensetzungen mit Bindestrichen immer groß schreiben). Demzufolge *Carbon-verstärkt*, aber *carbonverstärkt*.

Answer (score 3):

der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vitamin_B_haltig) sagt aber ausdrücklich

"Vitamin-B-haltig"  (groß geschrieben!)

Comment: Nehme ich mit Erstaunen zur Kenntnis.